# Algolia search query deformed inside Lambda function(using Serverless Framework) but works fine in Express

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, algolia

I'm getting the Algolia search request/query from the frontend into my Lambda function which then executes the request and returns the result.
The format of the request is an array like

```js
      [
        {
          "indexName": "indexname",
          "params": {
            "query": "querytext",
            "hitsPerPage": 7,
            "maxValuesPerFacet": 3,
            "page": 0,
            "facets": [
              "type"
            ],
            "tagFilters": "",
            "facetFilters": [
              "account_id:1"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
```

After that I search using their API client

```js
      const index = connectToIndex(ALGOLIA_APP,ALGOLIA_KEY,INDEX_NAME);
      const results = await index.search(requests);
```

Then the search query happens but I get 0 hits and when I `console.log(results)` the `query` field is deformed

```js
{
  "hits": [],
  "nbHits": 0,
  "page": 0,
  "nbPages": 0,
  "hitsPerPage": 20,
  "exhaustiveNbHits": true,
  "exhaustiveTypo": true,
  "query": "[{\"indexName\":\"indexname\",\"params\":{\"query\":\"querytext\",\"hitsPerPage\":7,\"maxValuesPerFacet\":3,\"page\":0,\"facets\":[\"type\"],\"tagFilters\":\"\",\"facetFilters\":[\"account_id:1\"]}}]",
  "params": "query=%5B%7B%22indexName%22%3A%indexname%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%22querytext%22%2C%22hitsPerPage%22%3A7%2C%22maxValuesPerFacet%22%3A3%2C%22page%22%3A0%2C%22facets%22%3A%5B%22type%22%5D%2C%22tagFilters%22%3A%22%22%2C%22facetFilters%22%3A%5B%22account_id%3A1%22%5D%7D%7D%5D",
  "renderingContent": {},
  "processingTimeMS": 1
}
```

but the `results` should be like below (This is what I get when I `console.log` on express server and I get the desired hits. Notice how it sends an object with `results` field and the `query` attribute contains only the searched text)

```js
{ results:
   [ { hits: [Array],
       nbHits: 20,
       page: 0,
       nbPages: 3,
       hitsPerPage: 7,
       facets: [Object],
       exhaustiveFacetsCount: true,
       exhaustiveNbHits: true,
       exhaustiveTypo: true,
       query: 'querytext',
       params:
        'query=querytext&hitsPerPage=7&maxValuesPerFacet=3&page=0&facets=%5B%22type%22%5D&tagFilters=&facetFilters=%5B%22account_id%3A1%22%5D',
       index: 'indexname',
       renderingContent: {},
       processingTimeMS: 1 } ] 
}
```

My issue is why it `console.log` 2 different things on lambda and express. I'm sending in the same `requests` array and using the same algolia API search in both occasions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it was a careless mistake
my `connectToIndex` returns an Algolia index

```js
const connectToIndex = (appId,apiKey,index) => {
  const client = algoliasearch(appId,apiKey);
  return client.initIndex(index);
};
```

and I have done the search using `index.search(requests)` which implies `client.initIndex().search(requests)`

But for searching you don't call `initIndex` instead you call the `search` method of the `client` directly

```js
client.search(requests)
```

I had correctly used this in express and somehow messed up inside the lambda
[Github issue](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-javascript/issues/1382)